# Laravel cron executes commands with two php versions

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-5, cron

While trying to execute a cron job using Laravel's scheduler, I get in the logs file that the commands are executing with `php7` and `php7.1` which is weird! can anybody explain what's happening?

Here is a screenshot of the content of the log file:

[image]

My crontab file looks like:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/ && php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/storage/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force specific version to be used by modifying your cron to:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/ && /usr/bin/php7 /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/storage/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

It could be that the cron is getting confused with which version of PHP to use since you have multiple versions installed.